# Cannot add an item into the dictionary from inherit class

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a "garage" where the user wants to store "robots" (imaginary, example). Information about the storage of all new robots should be written in a dictionary (place #: robots_name).

I created two classes:
1. "RicksGarage" - garage itself, where the robots will be stored. According to the exercise, adding method should be in this Class
2. Inherit class "LittleRobot" which initializes the new robot and contains the method of choice: if the user wants to delete or to add this robot.

**Task:** I need each new robot to be stored into the dictionary (place # : robots_name)

**Problem:** The dictionary overwrites every time new robots added

Could you advise, why is it happens? I assume I'm missing something in theoretical understanding

```
class RicksGarage():

    i = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.robots_places = {} # Dictionary, where new robot should be added

    def add_robot(self):
        self.robots_places[RicksGarage.i] = self.name
        RicksGarage.i += 1
        print(self.robots_places)

    def remove_robot(self):
        print("You deleted a Robot")



class LittleRobot(RicksGarage):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def choice(self):
        my_choice = input("Press '1' - to store the robot\nPress '2' - to remove the robot\n")
        if my_choice == '1':
            self.add_robot()
        elif my_choice == '2':
            self.remove_robot()
        else:
            print("You made a wrong choice, try again")

robot1 = LittleRobot("David")
robot2 = LittleRobot("Kevin")


robot1.choice()
robot2.choice()
```

Comment: A robot is not a subclass of a garage because it's not _a kind of_ garage. Rather, garage is a _collection_ of robots, each of which is independent. So the design is flawed, and because of that, each robot now has a `robots_places` attribute (why? it's the garage's attribute) which is reset to the empty dictionary each tie you initialise a new robot

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am still learning classes and sometimes confusing with such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
class RicksGarage():

    i = 1
    robots_places = dict()

    ...
    # than obviuously
        RicksGarage.robots_places[RicksGarage.i] = self.name
        RicksGarage.i += 1

    ...
```